How to resolve the problem with husky - pre-commit and eslint
In my project I have package.json:
//some settings 

 "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "0.14.0",
    "husky": "8.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "13.2.2",
  },

My .eslintrc.js settings :
module.exports = {
    'root': true,
    'env': {
        'browser': true,
        'es6': true,
        'node': true,
    },
    'extends': [
        'google'
    ],
    'globals': {
        'JSON5': 'readonly',
    },
    'parserOptions': {
        ecmaVersion: 8,
    },
    'ignorePatterns': ['index.js'],
    'rules': {
        'max-len': [
            'error',
            150
        ],
        'indent': [
            'error',
            4
        ],
        'prefer-const': 'error',
        'no-const-assign': 'error',
        'guard-for-in': ['off'],
        'valid-jsdoc': ['off'],
        'prefer-rest-params': ['off'],
        'prefer-spread': ['off'],
        'new-cap': ['off', {'newIsCap': false}],
        'semi': ['error', 'always'],
        'curly': ['error', 'all'],
        'space-in-parens': ['error', 'never'],
        'arrow-spacing': ['error', {'before': true, 'after': true}],
        'no-console': ['error', {allow: ['warn', 'error']}],
        'comma-dangle': ['error', {
            'arrays': 'never',
            'objects': 'always-multiline',
            'imports': 'never',
            'exports': 'never',
            'functions': 'never',
        }],
        'camelcase': 0,
        'no-undef': ['error'],
    },
};

But when I try to commit any js I get an error:
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: lint-staged@15.2.2
[STARTED] Preparing lint-staged...
[COMPLETED] Preparing lint-staged...
[STARTED] Running tasks for staged files...
[STARTED] .lintstagedrc.json — 4 files
[STARTED] *.js — 2 files
[STARTED] npx eslint
[FAILED] npx eslint [FAILED]
[FAILED] npx eslint [FAILED]
[COMPLETED] Running tasks for staged files...
[STARTED] Applying modifications from tasks...
[SKIPPED] Skipped because of errors from tasks.
[STARTED] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[COMPLETED] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[STARTED] Cleaning up temporary files...
[COMPLETED] Cleaning up temporary files...
✖ npx eslint:
Oops! Something went wrong! :(
ESLint: 9.0.0
Error: Could not find config file.
    at locateConfigFileToUse (...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\515228b7c8d004a2\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslint\eslint.js:349:21)
    at async calculateConfigArray (...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\515228b7c8d004a2\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslint\eslint.js:384:49)
    at async ESLint.lintFiles (...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\515228b7c8d004a2\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslint\eslint.js:814:25)
    at async Object.execute (...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\515228b7c8d004a2\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli.js:461:23)
    at async main (...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\515228b7c8d004a2\node_modules\eslint\bin\eslint.js:165:22)
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)


I know  ESLint 9.0.0 has a lot of critical changes, but I'm using
ESLint 8.15.0 in my project. However, the error still says about ESLint 9.0.0
I've tried set ESLINT_USE_FLAT_CONFIG = false to .env. But it didn't help
Maybe someone has encountered this problem? Any advice would help

Maybe the problem comes from using npx eslint instead of eslint directly?
